# How to calculate height/width based on CGPoint positions

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect, cgpoint

I have an array of 3 CGPoints, what I'm trying to do is create a CGRect based on those CGPoint coordinates.  I need this CGRect to set the bounds of a view so it can "zoom in" to those coordinates as soon as the view is loaded, but I'm not sure how to get the height and width.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the max and min values from an Array of CGPoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843897/get-the-max-and-min-values-from-an-array-of-cgpoints)

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let points: [CGPoint] = [
    .init(x: 1, y: 1), 
    .init(x: 5, y: 1), 
    .init(x: 8, y: 5)
]

let bounds = points.reduce(CGRect.null) { rect, point in
    return rect.union(CGRect(origin: point, size: .zero))
}
```